# Array coming up empty when rendering template rails 4

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, render, slim-lang

I have a controller, which only has one restful action- index. However, there was a lot of code in that one method, so I needed to break it up into two other methods- devices_table and results_table, but I still need everything to show up only on the index page. So, I created the two tables in their own views, and am using `render template:` to get the tables on the index page. Each table method has an array, which is iterated over in my view. When I declare the array variable in the table method, I get an error saying that it is nil. I figured out that I need to add the array variable into my index method so that it is available in the index view, since technically that is where all the html is being loaded. However, even though the array is now not nil, it comes up empty. I've tried everything I can think of- declaring the variable both in the index and table method, passing local variables along with the render template, but my arrays still come up empty. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

Controller (part of):

```
def index
  @business = Business.find params[:id]
  @mongo_db = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'test')
  @migration_ids = []
  @devices = []
end

def devices_table
  @business.devices.each do |device|
    @mongo_db[:migration_resources].find(:location => /.*#{device.uuid}.*/).each do |resource|
      migration_location = resource["location"]
      start_marker = "/migrations/"
      end_marker = "/folders/"
      @migration_ids << migration_location[/#{start_marker}(.*?)#{end_marker}/m, 1]
    end
  end
end
```

Index View (btw this is slim, not regular html):

```
#page-body
  .left-column
    .box
      = render template: 'admin/v3_migrations/devices_table'
```

Devices_table View:

```
.col-md-12
  h4= "Devices (#{@business.devices.count})"
  .table-wrapper
    table.table.table-hover
      thead
        tr
          th.col-md-1 ID
          th.col-md-3 Name
          th.col-md-3 UUID
          th.col-md-2 Status
          th.col-md-3 Migration UUID
          th.col-md-1
      tbody
        - @business.devices.each do |device|
          tr
            td= device.id
            td= device.name
            td= device.uuid
            td= device.status
            - @migration_ids.each do |id|
              td= id
              td= link_to admin_v3_migration_path(mig_id: id)
                i.fa.fa-download
```

If I instead write my controller like this, I get a nil class error on the array.

```
def index
  @business = Business.find params[:id]
end

def devices_table
  @business = Business.find params[:id]
  @mongo_db = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'test')
  @migration_ids = []

  @business.devices.each do |device|
    @mongo_db[:migration_resources].find(:location => /.*#{device.uuid}.*/).each do |resource|
      migration_location = resource["location"]
      start_marker = "/migrations/"
      end_marker = "/folders/"
      @migration_ids << migration_location[/#{start_marker}(.*?)#{end_marker}/m, 1]
    end
  end
end
```

Everything works great when all the code is in the single index method, so I know that it is not a database issue. Furthermore, everything is showing up in the table except the piece of data that I grab back out of my `@migration_ids` array, so I know that everything is rendering properly. I've tried so many different small tweaks, but I don't want to post all of the variations of code.

Comment: I don't see the devices array being initialized in the second example. Also, is devices_table being called?

Comment: I only put part of the controller up since the second table method (which is where the devices array is populated), looks almost exactly the same as the first. And devices_table has its own view, so I'm just rendering that. I'm not sure what you mean by calling it.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Is @business being initialized in devices_table? Are you able to see if it is getting the right id from the params?

Comment: I didn't initialize it in the first controller example, but it is getting the right param, which must be because when its initialized in index it holds the value. What I'm guessing the problem is with the arrays is that they are empty when initialized in index, and then for some reason, the values that get pushed in in the table methods get overwritten back to empty. But I can't figure out how to fix that.

Comment: In the second example, is atbusiness initialized though? Are you able to see definitively that atbusiness and atmongo_db both have values? Because atmigration_ids is relying on both of those.

Comment: Yes, second example I initialize it in both the index and table methods. And yes, I know atbusiness is showing the right value because all the other td's that don't rely on atmigration_ids give me the right data. And when I print out atmongo_db I get #<Mongo::Client:0x007fb056b36470> so I'm pretty sure that is working. Plus, if I nix all of the mongo stuff and just try to push in a string to the atmigration_ids array in the table method, it still doesn't show up. If I put in a string in the index method though it does show up. Its all very strange.

Comment: Is your code up on github by any chance? I'd like to try it out myself and see if I can debug it.

Comment: That would be awesome, unfortunately its in a private work repo. Thank you for all the follow up though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm yes, that is strange. When you print out atmongo_db, is it the same value as when you print it out for the first example?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. I finally just went to my superior (which I didn't want to do because it seemed like there must be an obvious answer that I was missing), and he advised me to just stick all the code back into the single index method, so I'm retiring this very curious Rails occurrence for now. Thanks for all the help, Kyle.